# Rep changes on Stack Apps are not reflected in StackExchange MultiCollider™ SuperDropdown

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog, stackapps

Seems to be the bug again. See, no entry for Stack Apps for yesterday, just SO and MSE:

> [image]

---

[I have earned 20 reps](https://stackapps.com/users/26439/nicael?tab=reputation) on Stack Apps today. But I am *not* seeing notifications for up votes in the drop down, however I see the number (etc +10).

Even when I recently got 10 reps on Stack Apps, I saw +10, but they can't be seen anywhere in my drop down.

> [image]

Halp? And yes, earlier (four days ago) everything worked fine.

Comment: Why downvote? You can't repro or... eh?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be finally fixed, and quite recently (and I haven't changed the browser):

> [image]

Comment: Aaaaand. It's broken again, wtf.

Comment: Not for me: http://i.imgur.com/2t3ql6G.png

Comment: @Glor yep, that's weird...